# AngularJS model Date property - wrong value is submitted to server?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime

weird things I am trying to understand, I am selecting a Date and time using datetimepicker, as you see on the screenshot

- the value in the textbox is correct
- the value of the model in console is correct (but wait just a sec... ;)
- the same value in the debug panel on the page is 4 hours more (the timezone offset) - why it's displayed like this - no idea, looks like the angular way html-render dates (+offset)

**But the weirdest thing is** that the "+4 hours" value is sent to the server when I click Submit :) `although in the console the value is correct`

Any explanation why it sends the value with the offset but not the one in the console, the one I want to submit ??

This is totally weird, any proper way to fix this?

I want the 13:30 to go to the server!

[image]

Comment: You can also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.scheduleReport))`. And look  value in json. I think there are 2 possible reasons why it is happening. 1) It is in your sumbit function 2) Some datepicker weird behavior about timezones

Comment: How do you submit the data? `Date().prototype.toJSON()` will produces ISO string using universal time  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

Comment: I submit like this: this.$http.post("/reportsweb//api/schedules/submitSchedule", model); what does it change? why values are different in console and in debug panel? they the value submitted is the wrong one (with the offset), when console shows the correct date?

Answer (score 1):

It is show simple, `DateTime` store on a server using **Universal Time Zone** and `DateTime` show on your console panel using **Eastern Time Zone**.[image: Google Result]. Its easy - [convert utc to local time angularjs](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convert%20utc%20to%20local%20time%20angularjs)

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, thats what happens when the date gets moved from server to client, and from client to server. trying to understand  - do I need to apply 2 conversions: when I get the date, and when I submit it?

Comment: You can apply 2 conversion or you can google **AngularJS date filter with UTC date** or **store local time on a server**. 3rd statement may be not possible using `DateTime` in my knowledge because server always uses UTC `DateTime`.

Comment: You can go through with 1st and 3rd comment. Either you can use `datetime` conversion on both time or you can use `varchar` to store local time on server as string.